# The brothers telling Yosef about Yosef

Tags: yosef, shevatim-12-tribes, miketz, vayigash

Rashi to Miketz ([Bereishit 42:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8237#showrashi=true&v=13)-14) says that the brothers told Yosef that they came to Egypt to look for their missing brother.

However, in Vayigash ([Bereishit 44:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8239#v=20)) Yehudah tells Yosef that they had told the viceroy that "his [Binyamin's] brother is dead."

How, then, could Rashi say that they had actually told Yosef that their brother was alive?

Comment: Nice question. [Rashi to 44:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8239#showrashi=true&v=20) says "ואחיו מת: מפני היראה היה מוציא דבר שקר מפיו" ...though that doesn't really answer the question, fully.

Comment: @Shokhet It seems like it does.

Comment: @Scimonster That was my first thought, but looking at the rest of the Rashi, it doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The *Mizrachi* (44:20) suggests that they said *Yosef* was missing when they first met him, but they said, when they next met him (with the gift of fruit), that he'd died.

The *Gur Arye* (44:20) suggests that by "dead" they meant "missing, presumed dead" (but they still sought him).